# What's the difference between matrix decomposition vs matrix factorization?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Not sure if "decomposition" meant for $A=\sum B_i$, and "factorization" is for $A=\prod B_i$. In Chinese, they are both translated to the same phrase "分解".

$LU$ is usually called "decomposition", but $A=LU$ more like a factorization. The same is for SVD. On the other hand, SVD can also be expressed as sum $A=\sum \sigma_iu_iv_i^T$, or in fact any product of two matrices can also be expressed as the sum of multiple rank-1 matrices. In this sense, the difference is a kind of blurred.

What piece of information I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Chinese well enough to be sure, but I suspect any 分解 is a "decomposition", though that might not be the most common English word in some contexts. Factorizations are just $A=\prod B$

Comment: You can try google translate or another translator. Here is [Chinese Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/). Sorry if I assumed the wrong language.

Comment: I would use factorisation as a specific type of decomposition into a product.

Comment: @copper.hat That makes sense. Thanks.